# Why does ping fail with "icmp open socket: Permission denied" on Bash on Win 10?

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my win10 machine in cmd prompt I've activated bash with

```
lxrun /install /y
```

then

```
neilh>bash  

root@NHPINSP:/mnt/c/Users/neilh# ping google.com  
$ su ping google.com  
"ping: icmp open socket: Permission denied"
```

It also fails as `sudo`, and `su`. This is a synthesis of a number of other actions. I initially installed with a username and was trying to do a `sudo apt-get update` but it failed. So I `lxrun /uninstall /full`, and then reinstalled the simplest setup to find out why the networking doesn't seem to be working.

My machine is "Test Mode" Windows 10  Home, Build 14393.187 (version 1607)

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/18.

ping doesn't currently work on WSL.

sudo and su not working are probably a result of the host file not being configured correctly. see this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1108197/sudo-on-windows-10-linux-subsystem-cannot-resolve-local-machine-name

Answer (score 3):

I open it with administration permission and then it works

Answer (score -2):

Luckily I found the answer here but it's for ubuntu:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=927709

```
sudo chmod u+s `which ping`
```